# Alternate for hash map

Tags: java

I have a set of objects of type "Part" and each Part is associated with quantity(a field that specifies number of units required of that particular Part ). Is there in way in java to store this data, **other than hash map**?

Comment: Java is an _object_ oriented language. That should give you a hint as to what you should do.

Comment: If you are simply trying to keep a count of the quantity required of each part, like a shopping list, then I'd say a `HashMap<Part>` is ideal. Why are you hoping to avoid the use of a `HashMap` in this case?

Comment: [What are you trying to achieve?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Comment: To elaborate on Francesco's comment: There are _lots_ of ways. But we can't really answer this well without knowing why HashMap doesn't work for you, and what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a wrapper object that has two fields, Part and quantity:

```
public class PartWithQuantity 
{
   private Part part;
   private int quantity;

   public int getQuantity() { return quantity; }
   public void setQuantity(int q) { quantity = q; }

   public Part getPart() { return part; }
   public void setPart(Part p) { part = p; }
}
```

You can also use a TreeMap if the concern is that the HashMap might use too much memory.

Comment: But without a lookup table such as a `HashMap<PartWithQuantity>` how do you jump to the `PartWithQuantity` which refers to the part of interest?

Comment: If you're storing it in a HashMap, that assumes that you have equals() and hashCode() defined already.  You could therefore use Apache Commons' CollectionUtils to search for it, or if the Parts are Comparable, use Collections.binarySearch() to look for it.

Comment: Apologies in advance if I misinterpret the solution. The class PartWithQuantity is simply  structured data, it is not having any other behavioural significance as such. Am I sounding sensible?

Comment: Correct.  If you cannot use a Map for storage, this may be the best way.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done very easily by just storing the metadata into the arraylist.
You can take a class that contains one reference of part type and other(quantity) is int type. Then you can even store the instances of this new class into an arraylist. Do Remember ,you can access your information anytime from this arraylist by calling the object.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve this would be to modify the `Part` class and add the `quantity` field, along with its setter and getter.

Another option would be to use a wrapper object and store it in the `Set`.
I have created a convenience method called `check()` to easily identify the `Part` of interest:

```
public class PartExtended {
    private Part part;
    private int quantity;
    public PartExtended(Part part, int quantity) {
        this.part = part;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
    public boolean check(Part part) {
        return part.equals(this.part);
    }
    public Part getPart() {
        return part;
    }
    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
}
```

To retrieve a `Part`'s `quantity`, use a `for` loop:

```
Set<PartExtended> data = new HashSet<>();
data.add(new PartExtended(new Part(), 0));

for (PartExtended item : data) {
    if (item.check(new Part())) {
        int quantity = item.getQuantity();
    }
}
```